# How to send a picture via email in Android, previewed but NOT attached..?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to send a picture preview in my mail Intent.
I dont want to attach it, i just want it to be shown.

This is my intent:

```
String textToSend = getString(R.string.mailHi)+"<br><br>"+getString(R.string.mailText)+getTextToSendViaMail();
                    Uri pngUri = null;
                    File currentShopImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/OpenGuide/"+Integer.toString(keyId)+"_1_normal.pn_");

                    if(currentShopImage.exists()){

                        File pngFile = new File(currentShopImage.toString());
                        pngUri = Uri.fromFile(pngFile);
                    }

                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.setType("text/plain");
                    //i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emailCim });
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "OpenGuide");
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(textToSend));
                    if(pngUri!= null)
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
                    try {
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, getString(R.string.SendMail)));
                    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(ShopActivity.this, getString(R.string.MailClientNotFound), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```

How can i achive such a thing ?

Comment: you want to send a picture, but not to attach it? how does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your problem, you want to place the image inside the mail with other text. In the words of Email protocol it's called an INLINE Attachment.

You would not be able to do this with `intents` as none of the email clients installed on the device supports creating html messages.

If it's really a core part of your app, you should consider a third party api to do this. One of the such library is [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html). You would be able to send html messages through this library but will take some time in setting up.

Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260654/embedding-images-into-html-email-with-java-mail/) that may give you some hint, how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

Then you need to send a HTML generated email afaik.