# How to embed image to E-Mail Body in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to Embed image to E-Mail body.How to do that.I found a lot but still cannot get the solution yet.Is it possible to add an image to E-Mail body?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148486/embedding-image-in-email-in-android

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13564225/1405120

Answer (score 0):

use Below code

```
Intent attachmentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
attachmentIntent.setType("image/*");
attachmentIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("your file address"));
startActivity(attachmentIntent);
```