# Embed images into template HTML Velocity in loop

Tags: java, html, apache, email, velocity

I know how to embed an image into a template.  [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331341/how-to-embed-images-into-template-html-velocity).  My question is how to do it in a loop:

```
<table>
     #foreach( $object in $objects )
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="cid:${image_cid}"/>
            </td>
...
```

The problem is I need to create a dynamic unique cid placeholder, e.g.:

```
<img src="cid:${object1_image_cid}"/>
....
<img src="cid:${object2_image_cid}"/>
```

I've tried using a variable inside of the ${image_cid} variable, but that just crashes.  e.g. I tried

```
${$object.id image_cid}
```

Any suggestions or ways to solve this?

Comment: You mean `<img src="cid:$object.cid" />` ?

Comment: Something like that yes.  Generate all of the cids and stick them on the object? Hmmm

Comment: Maybe you need to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941773/how-to-add-image-in-email-velocity-transformer-templates-from-classpath

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ismail for this suggestions.  Here's what I did.  In my Java code, I set all of the cids in a transient field on the object, e.g.:

```
for ( Object object : objects ) {
        String artworkCid = email.embed(file);
        object.setCid(artworkCid);
}
```

Then, in the template:

```
#foreach( $object in $objects )
      <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="cid:$object.cid" />
```

(obfuscated everything to object)